# How can I represent these tables in latex?

Tags: tables, tabularx, sidewaysfigure

I try to draw these tables in latex. I use in order to represent one table. How can I arrange the tables as in the picture? My code for one table:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.5cm
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}1 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 & \cellcolor{purple!20}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0& \cellcolor{blue!20}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0&\cellcolor{purple!20} 0 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to do this strictly within the tabular environment or would you like to use Tikz (graphics package in Latex) which probably provides an easier way to do this?

Comment: @ferstad I don't know how to use Tikz, that's why I use tabular . It doesn't matter what package I use.

Answer (score 2):

You fill the rest. I build a tabular consisting of blocks; the intercolumn space is suppressed and slight back up is inserted in order to compensate for the rules.

The user level syntax is easy to manage.

You may need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` if you're not running the latest LaTeX kernel.

Of course, if the table is not the one you want to reproduce, you should be clearer about your aim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\automatonrule}{mmm}
 {% #1 = rule number, #2 = output, #3 = list of blocks
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}\ttfamily
  \acedoong_automatonrule:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \acedoong_block:n
 {
  \int_if_odd:nTF { #1 }
   {% odd, black box
    \fcolorbox{black}{white}{\color{black}\makebox[\height]{1}}
   }
   {% even, white box
    \fcolorbox{black}{black}{\color{white}\makebox[\height]{0}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \acedoong_automatonrule:nnn
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{-\fboxrule}}c@{\hspace{-\fboxrule}}c@{}l@{}}
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 1 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 2 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 3 } } \\[-\fboxrule]
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 4 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 5 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 6 } } &
  ${}\rightarrow{}$\acedoong_block:n { #2 }  \\[-\fboxrule]
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 7 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 8 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 9 } } &
  \enspace\normalfont\itshape rule~#1
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\automatonrule{1}{0}{111 111 000}\quad
\automatonrule{6}{0}{111 100 100}\quad
\automatonrule{11}{0}{000 000 000}\quad
\automatonrule{16}{0}{001 011 111}

\bigskip

\automatonrule{2}{0}{000 000 001}\quad
\automatonrule{7}{0}{111 111 101}\quad
\automatonrule{12}{0}{001 111 111}\quad
\automatonrule{17}{1}{111 101 000}

\caption{Best packet of cellular automata rules found by genetic algorithm}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want black and white, here's the modified code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\automatonrule}{mmm}
 {% #1 = rule number, #2 = output, #3 = list of blocks
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}\ttfamily
  \acedoong_automatonrule:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \acedoong_block:n
 {
  \int_if_odd:nTF { #1 }
   {% odd, black box
    \colorbox{purple!20}{\makebox[\height]{1}}
   }
   {% even, white box
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\makebox[\height]{0}}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \acedoong_automatonrule:nnn
 {
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}l@{}}
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 1 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 2 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 3 } } \\
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 4 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 5 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 6 } } &
  ${}\rightarrow{}$\acedoong_block:n { #2 }  \\
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 7 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 8 } } &
  \acedoong_block:n { \tl_item:nn { #3 } { 9 } } &
  \enspace\normalfont\itshape rule~#1
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\automatonrule{1}{0}{111 111 000}\quad
\automatonrule{6}{0}{111 100 100}\quad
\automatonrule{11}{0}{000 000 000}\quad
\automatonrule{16}{0}{001 011 111}

\bigskip

\automatonrule{2}{0}{000 000 001}\quad
\automatonrule{7}{0}{111 111 101}\quad
\automatonrule{12}{0}{001 111 111}\quad
\automatonrule{17}{1}{111 101 000}

\caption{Best packet of cellular automata rules found by genetic algorithm}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I put an "x" in cell number 5 and change the color of this cell?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table of tables such as

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.5cm
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}1 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 & \cellcolor{purple!20}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0& \cellcolor{blue!20}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0&\cellcolor{purple!20} 0 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}1 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 & \cellcolor{purple!20}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0& \cellcolor{blue!20}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0&\cellcolor{purple!20} 0 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\\
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}1 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 & \cellcolor{purple!20}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0& \cellcolor{blue!20}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0&\cellcolor{purple!20} 0 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}1 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 & \cellcolor{purple!20}0 \\
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0& \cellcolor{blue!20}$P_0$ &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\cellcolor{purple!20}0&\cellcolor{purple!20} 0 &\cellcolor{purple!20} 1 \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

This is just 2x2 tables but can be extended. However if you want more control over the placing of the tables I would consider doing this in tikz:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Define colours
        \tikzstyle{my purple} = [fill=purple!20]
        \tikzstyle{my blue} = [fill=blue!20]
        % Plot one grid
        \draw[my purple] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
        \draw[my purple] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
        \draw[my purple] (2, 0) rectangle (3, 1) node[pos=.5] {1};
        \draw[my purple] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2) node[pos=.5] {0};
        \draw[my blue] (1, 1) rectangle (2, 2) node[pos=.5] {\(P_0\)};
        \draw[my purple] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2) node[pos=.5] {1};
        \draw[my purple] (0, 2) rectangle (1, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
        \draw[my purple] (1, 2) rectangle (2, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
        \draw[my purple] (2, 2) rectangle (3, 3) node[pos=.5] {1};
        \draw (0, 0) grid (3, 3);
        % Use same grid but move around using a scope and xshift/yshift
        \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
            \draw[my purple] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 0) rectangle (3, 1) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my blue] (1, 1) rectangle (2, 2) node[pos=.5] {\(P_0\)};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 2) rectangle (1, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 2) rectangle (2, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 2) rectangle (3, 3) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw (0, 0) grid (3, 3);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[yshift=4cm]
            \draw[my purple] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 0) rectangle (3, 1) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my blue] (1, 1) rectangle (2, 2) node[pos=.5] {\(P_0\)};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 2) rectangle (1, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 2) rectangle (2, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 2) rectangle (3, 3) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw (0, 0) grid (3, 3);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm, yshift=4cm]
            \tikzstyle{my purple} = [fill=purple!20]
            \tikzstyle{my blue} = [fill=blue!20]
            \draw[my purple] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 1) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 0) rectangle (3, 1) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my blue] (1, 1) rectangle (2, 2) node[pos=.5] {\(P_0\)};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw[my purple] (0, 2) rectangle (1, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (1, 2) rectangle (2, 3) node[pos=.5] {0};
            \draw[my purple] (2, 2) rectangle (3, 3) node[pos=.5] {1};
            \draw (0, 0) grid (3, 3);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Don't forget to put `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble.
[image: Tikz version of the tables]